# Хоровод - этимология

Tags: этимология

Каково происхождение слова "хоровод", с каким объективным явлением оно связано изначально?

Answer (score 6):

Версий много, многие раскритикованы. Мне кажется более объективной версия Даля.

По словарю В. Даля «хоровод» (харагод, ярогод и карагод, южн. круг, танок, улица) - собранье сельских девок и молодежи обоего пола на вольном воздухе для пляски с песнями; хороводные песни, особые, протяжные, и хороводная пляска, медленная, более ходьба, нередко с подражаньем в движеньях словам песни. Словарь этнографических терминов добавляет в это описание еще ряд названий – ёхор, коло, хейро, хора, хоруми.

Этимология слова «хоровод» указывает как будто бы на греческое его происхождение, хотя у южных славян, которые наиболее подверглись греческому влиянию, название аналогичной обрядности - чисто славянского происхождения ("коло").

Согласно расшифровке протославянского текста Фестского диска, бог Хор (древнерусский Хорс, египетский Хор) с эпитетом Коло - "Круг" - символ зимнего солнцестояния. Интересно отметить, что 25-му декабрю (близ зимнего солнцестояния) соответствует день Спиридона-поворота (Спиридона-Солнцеворота) в русском народном календаре. Бог Хор - божество солнечного светила (но не света). Солнечные знаки обозначали Хора как конкретное дневное светило ("око свету"). С его именем (в основном с понятием "круг", "коло" - коловорот, коловращение) и связаны ритуальные хороводы и русское слово "хорошо", т.е. солнечно. Не случайно, скифы назывались сколотами. Это с колоти - "народ возле солнца"

Так что **"хоро"-это круг, символ солнца.** А **вод - от "вести"**, кто-то ведёт всех по кругу. Хоровод - общее действо с песнями и плясками по кругу.

Есть более широкое понятие хоровода в славянской культуре. Оно совпадает с крестьянским понятием «улица» (ходить на улицу, ходить в хоровод; не пускать кого-либо на улицу, не пускать в хоровод) и обозначает всевесенне-летнее времяпрепровождение деревенской молодежи в разных его видах. Правда, русская деревня знала и зимние хороводы на улице, но это было редкостью.

Сами крестьяне, как и посторонние наблюдатели, пользовались словом «хоровод» тоже и в узком, и в более широком, и в самом широком смысле. Начинался хоровод часто так: две-три молодушки и столько же девушек-невест, живущих по соседству, становились посреди улицы и начинали «играть песни». К ним присоединялись постепенно многие молодые женщины и девушки. Затем, так же постепенно, подходили молодые мужчины и парни.Парни приходили нередко с гармониками, скрипками, бубнами. Мог возникать хоровод и иначе: в праздничный день в центре селения, где была ярмарка или некоторое подобие ее, несколько девушек сначала пели потихоньку «прибаутки», сидя рядом на бревнышке; парни подыгрывали им или подпевали слегка. Потом все вставали и, взявшись за руки, составляли круг. Тогда уже громко запевала одна изучастниц, а в середину круга выходил парень с платком в руках. Начиналась хороводная песня,сопровождающаяся пантомимой внутри круга.

Как видим, всё сводится к кругу.Вспомним древние "капища". Внешний круг предназначался для потребления людьми жертвенной ритуальной пищи и назывался "требищем". Круглая форма святилищ определила их название - "хоромы" (от "хоро"- круг), а в ином произношении - "храмы".

Кстати, **карагод (каракот, корогод)-то же самое, что хоровод,** только более древнее, сейчас диалектное.Это всё то же общеславянское слово **коло (круг)**. У южных славян хоровод с таким же исполнением и значением называется коло (круг). Здесь нужно только учесть известную редукцию р/л, а так же переход коро- в кара- в диалектной акающей языковой среде.

Из греческой мифологии известно прозвище Аполлона - Мусагет, то есть предводитель муз. Одной из функций Мусагета была организация хоровода для муз. Встав в круг, музы танцевали и пели под звуки золотой арфы, на которой играл Мусагет. Наши русские корни вод, гот и греческий гет означают одно и то же явление. У подножия Парнаса и далеко вдали от него жили многочисленные племенные предводители, которых называли αρχηγετης (архегет) - греч. предводитель, вождь племени. Есть позднее греческое слово лавагет - воевода, которое восходит к очень древнему слову rawaketa, то есть rawaketa = лаогет (λαογετης) = вождь людей, вождь народа. Это гомеровское выражение. Корень -ket- (-γετ-) неожиданно выводит нас на одну из научных публикаций. В этой публикации исследователи В.М. Сергеев и В.Л. Цимбурский считали, что встречающийся на древних критских печатях знак 74 = кошачья голова имеет прямое отношение к хаттскому слову katte, имеющему значение - царь. В греческом языке кот = γαττος. Не имеем ли мы здесь исторические и диалектные различия древних родственных языков ket - kat - γετ - γατ, не отсюда ли дошло до нас слово коро-гот, в значении предводитель круга?

Слово - год < - гот < гет = гат (кат) в значении, близком к значению слов водить, предводить > предводитель, вождь, царь существовало в середине II т.л. до н. э. в индоевропейской языковой среде Эгейского бассейна и в Малой Азии.

Comment: Энциклопедический словарь Ф.А. Брокгауза и И.А. Ефрона ведёт значение тоже от "коло" - круг.

Answer (score 1):

Что такое "объективное явление", сказать не могу, но хоровод — это то, что хором (т.е. совместно) водят.

Шанский, правда, приводит ещё одну, весьма экзотическую, версию, но, думается, за уши притянуто.

> Хоровод
>   хоровод Искон. Обычно толкуется как сложное слово на базе хор и водить. Некоторые ученые видят в нем народноэтимологическую «перестройку» диал. сев. корогод, заимств. из финск. яз. (ср. вепск. kargaidan «пляшу»). Школьный этимологический словарь русского языка. Происхождение слов. — М.: Дрофа Н. М. Шанский, Т. А. Боброва 2004

Comment: Хороводы в русском языке именно водят, а не пляшут и не танцуют.

Answer (score 0):

Хор - лошадь, овод - жалящее летающее насекомое. Хоровод - игра, где в центре круга стоит водящий, а вокруг - двигаются играющие. Смысл игры - изловчиться и хлопнуть по спине водящего так, чтобы он не успел вас коснуться. Если водящий Вас запятнал - Вы становитесь на его место. Подвижные игры на воздухе. Соответствует сельскохозяйственному укладу жизни. Имитирует сельскую реальность. Кому приходилось выбираться из города в деревню, где летом есть слепни, оводы и лошади,тот знает, насколько именно по кругу летают эти насекомые вокруг  Вашей головы, и, насколько мне не изменяет память, строго по часовой стрелке. В последнем могу ошибаться.
                               Случайный гость.

Comment: Изложенная версия не заимствована из каких-либо источников. Личное мнение. Считаю версию простой и естественной, хотя и внепарадигмальной. Допускаю, что игра в хоровод возникла не на Руси, а в англоязычных регионах, с последующей географической миграцией. Случайный гость.

Answer (score 0):

Огромное количество слов русского языка формируется вокруг языкового ядра — *кол.*
Это существительные: коло, кольцо, колокол, частокол, колодец, колдун, колода, колесница, околица, колыбель, коловращение (и ещё можно продолжить). Глаголы: колоть, колобродить, колдовать, колотить, колготать и т.д.
Коло — это не только движение по кругу, но и движение посолонь, т.е. по солнцу. А вот в слове "хоровод", восходящему к греческому "χορός" и русскому "коло" появилось два новых оттенка смысла. Первый — вести, т.е. наличие ведущего, чего нет в древнегреческом хоре. Второй — петь, т.е. движение хоровода часто совмещаются с пением. В хороводе появляется и вольность, он может двигаться не только посолонь, но и противосолонь, т.е. против солнца.

Answer (score 0):

Добавлю несколько слов из санскрита

- "kAra" - песня, хвала
- "karaka" - приветствие, оклик, зов
- "kAraka" - делание, действие, вызывание.
- "ga" - в целом движение, действие
- "gati" - двигаться, путь, проход, движение, поход, марш.

  "кара"+"гать" - движение с песней :)
  (слово "гать" осталось для разновидности насыпной дороги, а "кара" слилось с церковным "хор")

Answer (score 0):

Гораздо все проще.
На древнерусском "хора" означало "люди". До сих пор на болгарском, сербском, македонском это слово означает "народ", "люди".
"Вод" - "водить".
Почему никто не задумается, откуда вообще произошло слово ХОР? Хотя все понимают его значение.
Но ХОР и ХОРОВОД означают одно и то же.